# How to build this GA report

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics to track downloads of documents from my site using this code when the link is clicked:

```js
$('.nb_dl, .res_dl').on('click', function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var value = $(this).attr('rel');
    ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'click', value);
    document.location = url;
});
```

Where the value is formulated from the rel attribute like this:

```html
rel="Document Name | UserID | EventID"
```

(The EventID has nothing to do with the GA event being tracked)

How can I build a report to export that would show downloads of documents with certain names?

Or do you think there would be a better way to track these and build reports for certain types of documents (document names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [sample report using the Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3AtotalEvents&dimensions=ga%3AeventCategory%2Cga%3AeventAction%2Cga%3AeventLabel&sort=-ga%3AtotalEvents&filters=ga%3AeventCategory%3D%3DDownloads%3Bga%3AeventAction%3D%3Dclick&max-results=10) that should show your results:

The query params to use would look like this:

```
start-date: 30daysAgo
end-date: today
metrics: ga:totalEvents
dimensions: ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel
sort: -ga:totalEvents
filters: ga:eventCategory==Downloads;ga:eventAction==click
```

The key thing to notice is that I'm filtering the results to only show event categories that match "Downloads" and event actions that match "click".

For more information on filters and their syntax, take a look at the [filter reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters).

**IMPORTANT**

It's also worth pointing out that your hits may not be getting sent to Google Analytics since you're changing the URL immediately, and sometimes the browser will cancel pending requests when that happens. It's best to pass a `hitCallback` function and change the URL there, once you know the hit has been sent.

```
$('.nb_dl, .res_dl').on('click', function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var value = $(this).attr('rel');
    ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'click', value, {
      hitCallback: function() {
        document.location = url;
      }
    });
});
```

Note, that you should also add a timeout in the event that analytics.js fails to load, or something else happens that prevents the the `hitCallback` function from executing.

Comment: When I run that report, I get 0 results. I *know* there are results.

Comment: BTW, where did you get this parameter:`ga:91981236`

Comment: AFA the hitcallback is concerned. I don't know why I didn't do it that way. I'm doing it with a hitcallback for another type of URL 3 lines above this send call. (I shortened the actual code in my post)

Comment: If you *know* there are results then maybe you have a typo (e.g. "downloads" instead of "Downloads"). The `ga:XXXX` number is set by the Query Explorer. After you authenticate it just pulls in the first view ID (alphabetically) you have access to. You can change views to query a different view, which also may explain why you're getting 0 results (you're querying the wrong view).

Comment: I figured out what was wrong and how to get the `ga:xxxxx` number. Thanks for the help.